# Odoo Stock warehouse transfer issue

Tags: odoo-12, xml-rpc.net

I am trying to create stock request in Odoo version 12 through web service(xmlRPC). Stock Request and picking created in odoo but when i click on "In transit" type picking and then click on "Validate" button then It asked me "You have not

recorded done quantities yet, by clicking on apply Odoo will process all the reserved quantities." Then i click on "Apply" button it gives me error "It is not possible to unreserve more products of" .

Can anybody help me why i am getting this error what i am missing when create stock request through web service .

Answer (score 1):

Please update the done quantity field in the tree view as quantity ordered. If the product has lot update the done quantity by clicking on the bar icon in the line.